# Amazon Textract human_loop_config parameters available only on synchronous operations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-textract

Amazon Augmented AI (Amazon A2I) directly integrates with Amazon Textract's AnalyzeDocument API operation.

#analyze_document is a synchronous operation
#start_document_analysis is an asynchronous process

human_loop_config parameter can only be added to the available params in #analyze_document but not in #start_document_analysis

Please suggest if there is any way to send documents to Textract asynchronously with a human loop.

@aws-support-Team it would be great if you consider this as a feature request. also please let us know when this feature is going to be available

Comment: This feature is still not available, but you can find out more on this [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/issues/2318)